# WPF DataGrid Hangs UI when Refreshed

Tags: wpf, datagrid

I have a datagrid that has several things where it has dropdowns checkboxes and several different templated columns it also has large amount of data. The problem here is i am setting the property that disables cells and also doing a RaisePropertyChange on that propertybounded. Its updated only when i scroll down and load the data beneath. So i decided to send a Message and Refresh the items in grid.

Following code is for refreshing the grid when it recieves a message.

```
void RefreshGrid(RefreshGridMessage msg)
    {
        switch (msg.MsgType)
        {
            case RefreshGridMessage.MessageType.ExportChanged:

                this.Dispatcher.Invoke
                   (
                   new RefreshDelegate(
                       delegate
                       {
                           myGrid.Visibility = Visibility.Collapsed;
                           myGrid.Items.Refresh();
                           myGrid.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;
                       }
                      ),
                   null
                   );
                break;
        }
    }
```

The Problem here is it hangs up UI for few seconds and then it works perfectly and i will get the result what I need.

The question here is there any way to stop this hanging and make it work smoothly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you refreshing the data from another thread other than UI thread. In case you don't want your UI to be supsend for that time period use `BeginInvoke` instead of `Invoke` to queue it on Dispatcher.
The refresh delegate will be called `asynchronously` and your UI will remain responsive for that time period.

Comment: Sorry but it did not helped. its still hanging. and yes i am refreshing it from another thread.